# is there a way to use set with online comparator?

Tags: c++, set, comparator

i want to make a RedBlackTree using set or multiset with a comparator lambda function,and that function using an array(globally for simplicity)
the array is changing while program is running

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int v[10];
auto x = [](pair<int, int> p1, pair<int, int> p2) { return p1.second+v[p1.first] <   p2.second+v[p2.first]; };
set<pair<int, int>, decltype(x)> s(x);
// i tested multiset with same answer
int main()
{
    s.insert({3, 2});
    s.insert({4, 1});
    s.insert({2, 10});
    s.insert({8, 8});
    v[2]=-100;
    for (auto x : s)
        cout << x.first<<":"<<x.second << endl;
}
```

expect:

```
2:10
4:1
3:2
8:8
```

but i get this:

```
4:1
3:2
8:8
2:10
```

Comment: I don't think this can work. When there are elements already in the `set` you can't change the ordering on the fly (via some global in this case). It won't rearrange the container. You're just invalidating the invariant that was previously used to order the elements. This looks like a recipe for corrupting the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the array is changing while program is running

You are not allowed to have a comparator function that changes its behavior like that.

In your example, `set` is constructed before `v[2]=-100;` assignment, and it happens to just maintain its order after you make the assignment, but this is not guaranteed behavior.

As an aside, `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is non-standard and gets you downvoted on this site.